# Laravel belongsTo Relationship parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I have this two belongsTo code on a Model

[image]

so whenever i used something like

`$user->account()->is_provider` it returns null

and if i use

`$user->acc()->is_provider` it returns true/false depending on what user login

My question is what is difference of those two provided that i only add 3rd parameters on the middle of the first function ?

I will gladly update the question if needed more information or code

Comment: `public function belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $ownerKey = null, $relation = null)`

Comment: `$user->account()` is a `Builder` instance, not an `Account` model instance, so neither of your examples are correct. When defined properly (`public function account() { return $this->belongsTo(Account::class); })`; you don't need any of the extra stuff if `account_id` and `id` are the foreign/primary; Laravel auto-detects that based on the name), you'd need to use `$user->account->is_provider`, or `$user->account()->first()->is_provider`. (But, that code will cause an error if `$user->account` or `$user->account()->first()` are `null`; so careful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @aynber wants to say is that belongsTo relation should be defined as `return $this->belongsTo(Someclass::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');`

In your case:

```
return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'account_id', 'id');
```